# Cannot resolve method 'toString()

Tags: java, android

I want make String from int for TextView.
I have a code:

```
private TextView motivCountText;
private int motivCount;
...........................
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    motivCount = sPref.getInt(Constants.MOTIV_COUNT, 0);
    motivCountText.setText(motivCount.toString());
```

and I have a constant:

```
   public static final String MOTIV_COUNT = "saved_motivation_count";
```

and method toString() is red with comment: Cannot resolve method 'toString()

Comment: Primitive types (e.g. `int`) don't have a `toString()` method (or any method for that matter). Use `Integer.toString(motivCount)`

Comment: For what it's worth, you can in Scala, e.g., https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hcZSVcpbRHyM9kivAIfUYA or even with a literal, e.g., "`47.toString`". Probably the same in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

For interpreting Integer to String,

1. use String.valueOf method.

   motivCountText.setText(String.valueOf(motivCount));
2. add ""

   motivCountText.setText(motivCount + "");

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has a mistake, you can't call setText(int) this way because the int is interpreted as a Resource id int. If you try it you'll get a runtime error.

Instead, what you need to do is call

```
motivCountText.setText(""+motivCount);
```

The "" makes sure it's interpreted as a String. Last time I checked it was also the most performant way to create a String in cases like this.